Reqtify didn't match requirements between documents
I try to use reqtify to check if all my requirements, in my gherkin (feature format) are in an Excel table.
I created a new type for the "feature" format and duplicated a new type Excel to modify the right regex (a simple R_).
Rectify lists all the requirements in both documents but doesn't match them. I've only "Derived requirements".
I think I forgot an option or something else.
Does anyone have a solution?
Thanks
Yass
